# Cannot export data from Scrapy Spider, start_url undefined

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Fairly new to Python, following indications from DataCamp and youtube tutorials I'm trying to run a spider to crawl a website and extract metadata from the most recent (thousands) videos.

So far my Spider looks like this:

```py
class NaughtySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "naughtyspider"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_url = ("https://www.example.com/video?o=cm")
  # start_requests method
  def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url = start_url,
                         callback = self.parse_video)
  # First parsing method
  def parse_video(self, response):
    self.log('F i n i s h e d  s c r a p i n g ' + response.url)
    video_links = response.css('ul#videoCategory').css('li.videoBox').css('div.thumbnail-info-wrapper').css('span.title > a').css('::attr(href)') #Correct path, chooses 32 videos from page ignoring the links coming from ads
    links_to_follow = video_links.extract()
    for url in links_to_follow:
      yield response.follow(url = url,
                            callback = self.parse_metadata)
    #Continue through pagination
    next_page_url = response.css('li.page_next > a.orangeButton::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page_url:
        next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse_video)
  # Second parsing method
  def parse_metadata(self, response):
    # Create a SelectorList of the course titles text
    video_title = response.css('div.title-container > h1.title > span.inlineFree::text')
    # Extract the text and strip it clean
    video_title_ext = video_title.extract_first().strip()
    # Extract views
    video_views = response.css('span.count::text').extract_first()
    # Extract tags
    video_tags = response.css('div.tagsWrapper a::text').extract()
    del video_tags[-1] #Eliminate '+' tag, which is for suggestions
    # Extract Categories
    video_categories = response.css('div.categoriesWrapper a::text').extract()
    del video_categories[-1] #Same as tags
    # Fill in the dictionary
    yield {
        'title': video_title_ext,
        'views': video_views,
        'tags': video_tags,
        'categories': video_categories,
    }
```

I follow the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data-in-our-spider) where it introduces this seemingly simple way to export the scraped data

```py
scrapy crawl quotes -o quotes.json
```

but when I run the equivalent code

```py
scrapy crawl naughtyspider -o data.csv
```

I get the following error log:

```py
2019-08-17 22:24:54 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bla\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "C:\Users\bla\naughty\naughty\spiders\NaughtySpider.py", line 11, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Request(url = start_url,
NameError: name 'start_url' is not defined
2019-08-17 22:24:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Specially frustrating considering it is being defined in the previous line of code. I've seen similar situations in other questions, but none seems to fit exactly the code I'm using.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if there are major mistakes affecting the code, the resources around do not seem to be beginner friendly at all (no specification of which terminal / shell they are using, for example, mostly using Mac, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.` if you're referencing a **class variable**:

```
  def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url = self.start_url,
                         callback = self.parse_video)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to allow the code to execute. I tried an alternative to the pagination code, 

"#Continue through pagination
    next_page_url = response.css('li.page_next > a.orangeButton::attr(href)').extract_first()
    next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    if '&page=2' in self.next_page_url:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.next_page_url, callback=self.parse_video)
    else: 
        raise CloseSpider"

But I do get the same error that the variable next_page_url is undefined, even after using self.?

Comment: @Kuku You can post your updated code and ask another question for new error.